# How to store netty Channel object in Redis database or any other solution?

Tags: java, redis, netty

As i am using netty to make chat application.As i have cluster of netty servers.

As i am storing channel id of all clients in Redis to have reference of all channels which are connected to netty servers.

I want to store all Channel objects to Redis so that from any node or instance i can get all clients Channel objects because node on which if i want to get other clients Channel which are created on some other node, How to get those client Channel objects which reside on other node or instance?

So its better to store client Channel object to redis so from any node i can get any client Channel object. but Channel implementing class is not Serializable in netty.

1. So how to store Channel object in Redis?
2. Is it good idea to serialize Channel object by extending Channel
   object and implementing Serializable interface?
3. If this solution is not good, then how to get any client Channel
   object from any node in a netty cluster?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Channel in Netty contains implicitely all network aspects (socket, nio support, tcp or udp or ...), therefore you can not serialize it (a network connection cannot be serialized).

But you can serialize the remote address. Note however that the "id" is not configurable, meaning you cannot force its value for one channel. So you might use something like:

In Redis or so: (your id being the key)

- your id
- remote host address (and port probably)
- any data for the context

In your JVM (node): (map where your id is the key)

- your id
- the channel object

Comment: As you told to store remote node address of client but when message comes in to netty server from sender and got the receiver node remote address from redis, but how to transfer message to that remote node address so that it can be consumed by receiver client? Which service can be used of AWS to pass message to that netty node(from sender netty node to receiver netty node) or any other custom solution?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can store or persist Netty Channel in Map other than Redis.Because the channel object is unserializable.